# hover not active when hovering over sprite image in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, hover, css-sprites

Here is a toughie.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XvMpK/)

I have a link that opens up a video player(see below). The isotope hydrology image is the links image, and the play button image is within a `span` as a background image.

[image]

I am using a css sprite so that when someone hovers over any part of the image, the play image will change to what is below.

[image]

This works fine in all browsers except IE. In IE9, when I hover over the the isotope hydrology image it changes color and is clickable(like the image above). But when I hover over the actual play button, it switches from the blue "active" play button(above) to the grey "inactive" play button (top image) and it is not clickable.

**I created the images below to illustrate what is happening:**

[image]

This is when you hover over the isotope hydrology image (which is what i want to happen)

[image]

Once I hover over the play button (which is a span background image), this is what it looks like.(the cursor becomes a text cursor and the css sprite changes back to the non-hover color)

any help with this would be awesome.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="news-video" class="news-tab">
                        <div id="video-box-left">
                            <div class="video-img">
                                <a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://wwwindex.html','photoessay','scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,width=850,height=722')"><span class="video-play-q-left">play</span><img src="resources-na/images/video-amano-scientific-forum.PNG" alt="Isotope Hydrology - The Fingerprints of Water" width="200" height="155" border="1"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="video-text">
                                <p><strong>Food for the Future - Meeting Challenges with Nuclear Applications - Statement to 2012 Scientific Forum</strong><a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www-','photoessay','scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,width=850,height=722')"></a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="video-box-right">
                            <div class="video-img">
                                <a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www-','photoessay','scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,width=800,height=600')"><img src="resources-na/images/video-isotope-hydrology.jpg" alt="Isotope Hydrology - The Fingerprints of Water" width="200" height="155" border="1"><span class="video-play-q-right">play</span></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="video-text">
                                <p><strong>Isotope Hydrology - The Fingerprints of Water</strong><a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://.html','photoessay','scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,width=850,height=722')"></a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Here is the css:

```
#news-video {
    color: #8A8A8A;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 1.6667;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

#video-box-left{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 210px;
}
#video-box-right{
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 210px;
}
.video-img {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 155px;
}

.video-text {

}

.video-play-q-left {
    background: url("../images/video-play-q-big.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background-position: center top;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    width: 50px;
    left: 100px; 
    top: 127px;
}
.video-play-q-right {
    background: url("../images/video-play-q-big.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background-position: center top;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    width: 50px;
    left: 321px;
    top: 127px;
}

a:hover .video-play-q-right{
    background-position: center bottom;
}

a:hover .video-play-q-left{
    background-position: center bottom;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a working example in a jsfiddle?

Comment: It'd be my first time, but i'll try

Comment: It's worth the try, believe me.

Comment: @yunzen added a jsfiddle

Comment: As you see, the fiddle does not recreate the problem, so it must be somewere else in yout code. Do you have a special ie.css file? Also try to inspect the elements and copy the css of every parent elements into your fiddle as well

Comment: @yunzen I know what your saying, but will jsfiddle replicate a problem that only occurs in IE??

Comment: If I look at the fiddle in IE it maybe will do it.

Comment: @yunzen I have tried that, and it has not replicated the problem. I believe the problem has something to do with the text-indent not working in IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `DOCTYPE` tag was forcing IE to go into "IE9 Compatibility View".

I changed the tag and it was fine.

Thanks for the help everyone.